# Architectures that take inputs of mixed sampling rates

Tags: time-series, dataset, data-cleaning, convolutional-neural-network

Let's say a model is trained on multiple datasets of 1D time series. These datasets have been gathered with different sampling rates. I plan to use a convolution neural network to process these time series for classification.

My question is, in this scenario, are there any tricks I can do to the data or the model itself to make it "aware" of the sampling frequency? I've tried naively just training them together, and I'm getting an ok result.  Are there any existing works? I tried googling but found nothing worth noting as of now.

I'm hesitant about just resampling the data is I don't want to accidentally remove/introduce important information by making the method of interpolation a hyperparameter.

Answer (score 0):

With a search online, I couldn't find a satisfying answer, so I came up with a way. I tested and it gave pretty nice accuracy. This method is inspired by [this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Chen_Dynamic_Convolution_Attention_Over_Convolution_Kernels_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf).

Similar to the approach in the paper, I first select the number of convolution kernels I want to use, and depending on the sampling rate of a data point, I apply convolution to it using the convex hull of the set of convolution kernels.

So how exactly do I come up with the weight? There are a lot of hyperparameters, but what I did is assign a sampling rate to each kernel by dividing up the expected range of sampling frequency. I then subtract the sampling rate of the input datapoint to see which kernel is the closest to it. Then I take a softmin of the absolute difference, which makes sure the resulting weights add up to 1.

There are many things to play around here: Do we uniformly assign the rates? How many kernels to use in a set? How do you calculate the weight?...